# Is running MacOS software on Linux better than running Windows software on the latter?

Tags: linux, debian, windows, macos, darwin

MacOS's kernel is based on FreeBSD, Darwin, and a few other forgotten ones, all of which are monolithic, I believe. However, the current MacOS kernel, XNU, is hybrid, which is one of the things that draws it away from the other popular UNIX-like alternatives (e.g. Linux, BSD, etc.)

Question: Does MacOS software being designed for a UNIX-like kernel make it easier to run on Linux than Windows software? By "easier" I *do not mean* easier to set up. That I don't care. I mean easier to run, in the sense "takes up less juice / less likely to bug".

Note: I tried to make my question as clear as possible. If I'm lacking detail in explaining what I want to know, just tell me. I'm not very experienced with Linux quite yet, so there might be "obvious" things that I didn't take into consideration.

Comment: What kind of software? Anything with a GUI is likely to be just as hard to make work in Linux as any Windows software, and at least for Windows Valve has got Proton running many games *very* well
 I don't see anybody doing something similar for Mac software

Comment: Why do you think the kernel concept is relevant for which software runs "better"?

Comment: @Philippos It was rather hoping than thinking. I know it's possible to install APTs (which are really just archives) on non-Debian-derived Linux distros, for example, because of the kernel similarities. Same for installing Linux software on BSD-family systems. That's where the idea came from, if it makes any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The fact that they are both UNIX-like kernels means very little- the kernels are utterly incompatible with one another.

Whether it's Windows or MacOS programs you're trying to run on Linux, you're forced (at a minimum) to implement an abstraction layer that intercepts all system calls and takes the proper actions so that the program believes it is interacting with the kernel it was built for. You also need to implement a whole bunch of user-space stuff that every program expects to be available. `dyld` on MacOS, for instance, which is used by every program and is not similar to anything in Linux.

Windows and MacOS both also use different native binary formats than Linux (respectively, PE, Mach-O, and ELF files), so there is no benefit there either.

Comment: It's not only the kernel interaction but the whole operating system API. To my knowledge MacOS is moving more and more device drivers that classically were kernel drivers out of the kernel.

Comment: @Philippos Yes, that was the sort of thing I was getting at with "a whole bunch of user-space stuff."